# Prevent pull requests from defaulting to upstream repo

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I've forked a repo on Github and done some work on it, but my PRs keep defaulting to the upstream repo and not my repo, so I've made a few accidental PRs to the wrong repo.  How can I change the default behavior?

Comment: How do you make your PRs?

Comment: By going to my repo on Github.com and clicking "New Pull Request".  After doing that the PR form defaults to the upstream repo, which causes some mistakes.

Comment: I have the same question, how did you solve eventually?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573448/how-to-set-default-fork-for-pull-requests - no conclusion that helps, but it is the same question.