# github pull request to current repository

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am working on a opensource project that was forked to my company github account. Here my team made some changes and want to create PR to the forked repository (not the base repository). But every time when we try to create PR we have to manually set our repository from the repository list then have to select the branch.

My question is: **Is there a way that always my company repository will be selected by default?**

Because sometime it is very disturbing to search my repository from the bunch of all other forks. Its really annoying that sometime it took time to switch repository. And sometime unintentionally creates PR to wrong repository
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default fork for pull requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573448/how-to-set-default-fork-for-pull-requests)

Comment: @kutschkem yes you are right but the answer is not what I desire :(

Comment: Well of course, but I fear there is no better answer, I saw at least one other question than the one I linked that also had no good answer.

Comment: Ask Github for help. If they provide answer then I will post it or will close the questions if they didn't response :(

Answer (score 2):

As @robrich suggested in his SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012787/7905714), it appears you're doing some push and commit heavily, and having to keep selecting your company's account all the time you create PR to have to manually set your repository from the repository list then have to select the branch, is very consuming and can be annoying, I also suggest you should contact [GitHub customer support](https://github.com/contact) to help you instead.

Comment: Yes its really annoying and some time it took time to switch repository. And sometime unintentionally creates PR to wrong repository :(

Comment: I like this out-of-the-box thought, maybe it is possible for the support to set the base fork, something I don't think is possible through the UI otherwise.

Comment: yea @kutschkem anything is possible, he might be lucky enough to get his problem fixed from their side.

Answer (score 0):

1.On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

2.Under your repository name, click Settings

3.n the default branch sidebar, choose the new default branch. [enter image description here][1]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
git add -A
commit -m "you message"  
git pull "origin master or branch name"
```

Comment: You might want to improve your answer by adding commentary describing what your code does and why this solves the problem of the OP. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)